# Is using XSP4 from Mono behind Nginx as a reverse proxy production proof?

Tags: asp.net, nginx, mono, reverse-proxy, xsp4

When reading the [Mono docs](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/aspnet/), it says that XSP is not suited for production:

> For quickly getting started, get familiar with Mono and ASP.NET, XSP
>   is the ideal solution. Keep in mind that XSP is a very limited server
>   and is only useful to get acquainted with ASP.NET and Mono, it only
>   support HTTP 1.0 and does not provide much extensibility or
>   configuration.

We are developing a REST API, and are thinking of the following setup:

- Linux server
- ASP.NET with Mono
- Run in XSP4
- Nginx as reverse proxy (which can handle load balancing, caching, static files, etc.)

But I'm wondering whether the remarks about XSP not suited for production only apply to the configuration part, or would it also be for performance?
Our performance demands are mainly for large requests, not so much for processing high number of requests (but if necessary, we could scale up with multiple instances of the application in XSP4).

Comment: This is very subjective based upon your application needs. XSP4 works fine but there are scaling issues of course but that depends upon your usage pattern. Assuming you plan on having UI driven and web service test cases, you can you those to drive a stress related test. Also you can include in your  project plans to move it to a fast-cgi approach

Comment: But what is the main difference between fast-cgi and xsp4 that makes the former the default choice, and the latter only something for testing? In function they are basically the same..

Comment: If you spend some time with the XSP code base, you will see that there are limitations in what it can (ie. http 1.0, compression, etc..) do and how well it does it in a stressed environment (dealing with thread pool, domain separation, security, etc..). MSFT has an IIS that installs on their desktop OSs but I doubt there are many production systems that are playing Windows 8.1 in the data center... ;-) Again, it is a very subjective question and really needs to be tested for what your usage patterns will be. Most envs that "I" know of use Nginx fast-cgi with Mono, but not all...

Comment: Thanks for the addition. Luckily ASP.NET can be run on linux now with ASP.NET5, so we will be going for kestrel and nginx reverse proxy :)